# PHP Laravel 4 Array to nested JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `Laravel 4`. I am at beginner stage so I am not fully aware of features of `PHP` as well as `Laravel` framework.

I have an array that is fetched from a table like below :

```
$result = model::all();
```

that gives :

```
[0]=>[
       [id]=>1
       [name]=>"abc"
       [description]="temp"
       [tempfield1]="t1"
       [tempfield2]="t2"
       [tempfield3]="t3"
]
[1]=>[
       [id]=>1
       [name]=>"xyz"
       [description]="temp2"
       [tempfield1]="t21"
       [tempfield2]="t22"
       [tempfield3]="t23"
]
... and so on.
```

Now, I want to generate JSON from this array something like this :

```
"items":[{
    "id": 1, 
    "name":"abc", 
    "description":"temp",
    "temps":[{
            "temp1":"t1", 
            "temp2":"t2", 
            "temp3":"t3", 
           }]
    }, 
    {
    "id": 2, 
    "name":"xyz", 
    "description":"temp2",
    "temps":[{
            "temp1":"t21", 
            "temp2":"t22", 
            "temp3":"t23", 
           }]
    }
    ... and so on
]
```

To achieve this, I have created an Item class that have properties Id, name and description.

```
Class Item{
   public $id; 
   public $name; 
   public $description; 
}
```

Also have created a Temp class that extends Item class and having properties temp1, temp2 and temp3.

```
Class Temp extends Item{
   public $temp1; 
   public $temp2; 
   public $temp3; 
}
```

What my idea is to create a list of type `class Temp` and create a `foreach` loop which fetch each record from the array given above and populate the object of `Temp` class with respective properties and then I will push that object to the list. For example,

```
$list = array(); 

foreach ($result as $row){

     $objTemp = new Temp(); 
     $objTemp->id = $row["id"]; 
     $objTemp->name = $row["name"]; 
     $objTemp->description= $row["description"]; 
     $objTemp->temp1= $row["tempfield1"];       
     $objTemp->temp2= $row["tempfield2"];       
     $objTemp->temp3= $row["tempfield3"];       

     list->push($objTemp);
}
```

And then my idea was to convert list to JSON. But I am failed to achieve so. Even `print_r($objTemp)` gives me list as a flat structure, not with nested temp fields.

Can anyone help me to achieve the nested JSON using this flat array please?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I thinks there are no experts available for Laravel on stack-overflow yet. .NET is better than Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller just put:

```
return Response::json($result);
```

But you should define a relationship between Item and temp (something like):

```
Class Item extends Eloquent{
   public $id; 
   public $name; 
   public $description; 

    public function temps()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Temp','user_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. But in this case where should I populate "Temp" object with array() elements?

Comment: Well I think you should keep in Temp 'id' and 'name' (or similar), and  normalize your database (even if you know that you store maximum 3 temp`s) my opinion

Comment: That is not possible for me as I want to create more classes that extends Item class having same properties Name, Id and Desription but different in each class.

Comment: You must define each property (name,id,description) for each class then, no big deal